# Create a flexible view of a table

Tags: excel, view, pivot-table, vlookup

I have a table in Excel that contains all the information around my test cases (TESTDATA table). Some fields are relevant for a specific category but might not exist on other categories.

```
TESTDATA

TestId    Test Description  Category   FieldA    FieldB   FieldC
1         Test 1 Desc        CAT1        XYZ       ABC     WWW
2         Test 2 Desc        CAT1        XYZ       ABC     WWW
3         Test 3 Desc        CAT2                  ABC     WWW
4         Test 4 Desc        CAT2                  ABC     WWW
5         Test 5 Desc        CAT3        XYZ               WWW
```

I want to create separate tables that would display the relevant data for each category only.

```
CAT1 Test Data Table
TestId    Test Description  Category   FieldA    FieldB   FieldC
1         Test 1 Desc        CAT1        XYZ       ABC     WWW
2         Test 2 Desc        CAT1        XYZ       ABC     WWW


CAT2 Test Data Table
TestId    Test Description  Category   FieldB   FieldC
3         Test 3 Desc        CAT2      ABC     WWW
4         Test 4 Desc        CAT2      ABC     WWW


CAT3 Test Data Table
TestId    Test Description  Category   FieldA    FieldC
5         Test 5 Desc        CAT3        XYZ     WWW
```

The ideal solution for that would be to have something similar to a PivotTable in which I could select what fields I want to show on that particular table (or view) and filter appropriate data by Category, but PivotTable seems to allow only SUM/AVERAGE/MIN/MAX.

Is there any way of doing it with this kind of flexibility?

My current solution is using VLOOKUPS but maintenance is very time consuming.

Comment: You could try changing the Design of the pivot table and put all the information under 'Row Labels', change the Report Layout to 'Tabular Form' (Alt + JY + P + T), 'Repeat All Item Labels' (Alt + JY + P + R) and hide the subtotals through 'Subtotals' > 'Do Not Nhow Subtotals' (Alt + JY + T + D)

Comment: Great! Thanks Jerry. That's exactly what I needed. Thanks for the precision while describing the solution.

Comment: @pnuts: this is not actually a problem since I can create as many tables as I have categories on the main list and select different fields on each one. Cheers!

Comment: pnuts, you are right. Any change on the layout would have to be manually replicated on the tables by adding a new field to the Row Labels.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if it could be improved in order to allow user to input the test result. Since PIVOT tables are for reporting, it won't allow me to write data on it ans see it being replicated into the main table (TESTDATA). Am I right?